# Google Collab:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Tensorflow/workspace/annotations\\label_map.pbtxt'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tensorflow, object-detection

I'm trying to do an object detection project using tensorflow and this is stopping me since 3 days.

```
WORKSPACE_PATH = 'Tensorflow/workspace'
SCRIPTS_PATH = 'Tensorflow/scripts'
APIMODEL_PATH = 'Tensorflow/models'
ANNOTATION_PATH = WORKSPACE_PATH+'/annotations'
IMAGE_PATH = WORKSPACE_PATH+'/images'
MODEL_PATH = WORKSPACE_PATH+'/models'
PRETRAINED_MODEL_PATH = WORKSPACE_PATH+'/pre-trained-models'
CONFIG_PATH = MODEL_PATH+'/my_ssd_mobnet/pipeline.config'
CHECKPOINT_PATH = MODEL_PATH+'/my_ssd_mobnet/'
```

This got compiled.

```
labels = [{'name':'A', 'id':1}, 
          {'name':'B', 'id':2},
          {'name':'C', 'id':3},
          {'name':'D', 'id':4},
          {'name':'E', 'id':5},
          {'name':'F', 'id':6},
          {'name':'G', 'id':7},
          {'name':'H', 'id':8},
          {'name':'I', 'id':9},
          {'name':'K', 'id':10},
          {'name':'L', 'id':11},
          {'name':'M', 'id':12},
          {'name':'N', 'id':13},
          {'name':'O', 'id':14},
          {'name':'P', 'id':15},
          {'name':'Q', 'id':16},
          {'name':'R', 'id':17},
          {'name':'S', 'id':18},
          {'name':'T', 'id':19},
          {'name':'U', 'id':20},
          {'name':'V', 'id':21},
          {'name':'W', 'id':22},
          {'name':'X', 'id':23},
          {'name':'Y', 'id':24},
          ]

with open(ANNOTATION_PATH + '\label_map.pbtxt', 'w') as f:
    for label in labels:
        f.write('item { \n')
        f.write('\tname:\'{}\'\n'.format(label['name']))
        f.write('\tid:{}\n'.format(label['id']))
        f.write('}\n')
```

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-294439053577> in <module>()
     25           ]
     26 
---> 27 with open(ANNOTATION_PATH + '\label_map.pbtxt', 'w') as f:
     28     for label in labels:
     29         f.write('item { \n')

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Tensorflow/workspace/annotations\\label_map.pbtxt'
```

I'll be really grateful if someone can help me!

Comment: use `/full/path/to/file` or at least check in which folder it runs code `os.getcwd()` (current working directory) or what you have in current working directory `os.listdir()`. Probably code runs in different folder then you expect and it can't find your subfolder - maybe even it can't find subfolder `Tensorflow`

Answer (score 1):

Check your current working directory with `!pwd`.

It may be that you are in the wrong folder or inside the Tensorflow folder from where you are not able to access ANNOTATION_PATH.

In case, you are inside Tensorflow folder, use `%cd ../` ( to go a folder back) and also change `\label_map.pbtxt` to `/label_map.pbtxt`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the full path
for example if that is in D folder
the path should be
WORKSPACE_PATH = 'D:/Tensorflow/workspace'